# In Mississippi, is there a law that states your home and auto have to be insured with the same company?

Tags: united-states

In Mississippi, is there a law that states your home and auto have to be insured with the same company? I was getting quotes from a company for a rental property we own, and was told that in MS they could not insure that property without insuring our residence and vehicles with that company.  I've never heard that, so I wanted to make sure there wasn't some law or statute that said that this was the case.

Comment: I've looked through the titles of the state statutes and insurance regulations and there seems to be no legal basis for thinking that, but one would have to read the thousands of pages of insurance law to be sure. It might be a company policy designed to drum up business – and I don't know if *that* is legal, either.

Comment: It's *really* hard to prove a negative (e.g., "No such law exists.").  It would be very easy for them to prove that they're not making it up by them providing you with the name of the law or reference to the statute they claim exists so you can check yourself.